# Calculating particle size and distance between them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, particles

I'm trying to display an image with particles. It works, but the amount of particles is dependant on a variable (numberOfParticles) that can range between 0 and 3000. On any value, the image should be rendered in the best way possible with the given amount of particles. There is a nested for loop that goes through the image data (height and width) and creates particles like this.

```
for (var y = 0; y < data.height; y+=averageDistance) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.width; x+=averageDistance) {
        if (particles.length < numberOfParticles){
            var particle = {
                x0: x,
                y0: y,
                color: "rgb("+data.data[(y * 4 * data.width)+ (x * 4)]+","+data.data[(y * 4 * data.width)+ (x * 4) +1]+","+data.data[(y * 4 * data.width)+ (x * 4) +2]+")"
            };
            particles.push(particle);
        }
    }
}
```

Later in the code, the particles get rendered with a given size.

My question is, how do I calculate the size the particles should have and the distance that should be between them?

I've tried calculating the 'average distance', counting the amount of pixels that are not covered by particles and dividing that through the amount of particles, but I can't get it to work correctly. There's always leftover space (so the bottom part doesn't get filled) or leftover particles (so there are only 40 particles shown, instead of 50) on some value of the variable numberOfParticles.

Comment: Your question implies it, but your particles are all the same size, yes?

Comment: @markE Yes, they're all the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to the mathematical part can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039482/how-to-evenly-space-a-number-of-points-in-a-rectangle/1039514#1039514).

To find number of points for x (***n<sub>x</sub>***) we can use that formula:

[image: nx]

Then number of points for y (***n<sub>y</sub>***):

```
ny = n / nx
```

**In JavaScript code:**

```js
nx = Math.sqrt((w / h) * n + Math.pow(w - h, 2) / (4 * Math.pow(h, 2))) - (w - h) / (2 * h);
ny = n / nx;
```

Using the numbers nx and ny we can then calculate the deltas for x and y:

```js
dx = w / nx;
dy = h / ny;
```

### Example

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), n, w, h, nx, ny, dx, dy, x, y;

// define values
n = 1600;
w = c.width - 1;   // make inclusive
h = c.height - 1;

// plug values into formula
nx = Math.sqrt((w / h) * n + Math.pow(w - h, 2) / (4 * Math.pow(h, 2))) - (w - h) / (2 * h);
ny = n / nx;

// calculate deltas
dx = w / nx;
dy = h / ny;

// render proof-of-concept
for(y = 0; y < h; y += dy) {
  for(x = 0; x < w; x += dx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (360*Math.random()) + ",50%,50%";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, dx-1, dy-1);
  }
}

o.innerHTML = "Points to place: " + n + "<br>" + 
  "<strong>n<sub>x</sub></strong>: " + nx.toFixed(2) + "<br>" + 
  "<strong>n<sub>y</sub></strong>: " + ny.toFixed(2) + "<br>" +
  "ΔX: " + dy.toFixed(2) + "<br>" +
  "ΔY: " + dy.toFixed(2) + "<br>" +
  "Total (nx × ny): " + (nx * ny).toFixed(0);
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=400></canvas>
<br><output id=o></output>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Best fit maintaining aspect.

These types of packing problems come up a lot in CG.

To fill a square box with smaller square boxes you just need to find the square root of the count you want.

```
var c = 100; // number of boxes
var w = 10; // box width
var h = 10; // box height
var sW = 1000; // screen width
var sH = 1000; // screen height
```

The fit is `sqrt(c) = sqrt(100) = 10`. That's 10 across, divide the screen width by the count sW/10 = 100 to get the width of the box so that 100 will fit the screen.

This works for counts that are squares of integers, if no square root we can factorise to find a better solution. But even then there is not always a solution that fits.

**Prime numbers will never fit**

Any count that is a prime number will not have a solution, it is impossible to fit a prime number into x rows of y columns. This is because the resulting count is x * y and that means its not a prime.

**Compromise**

In the end you will need to compromise. Either you control the count to only allow counts with a solution (not a prime) or you accept that there will be some error and allow the solution to go outside the bounds.

This solution will fit but will allow the count to change and the area outside the screen to be at a minimum while still maintaining the box aspect ratio.

The width count is the sqrt((c / sA) * bA) where sA is the screen aspect and bA is the box aspect.

```
var c = 100; // number of boxes
var w = 10; // box width
var h = 10; // box height
var sW = 1000; // screen width
var sH = 1000; // screen height
var sA = sH / sW; // screen aspect
var bA = h / w; // box aspect
var wCount = Math.sqrt((c / sA) * bA); // get nearest fit for width
wCount = Math.round(wCount); // round to an integers. This forces the width to fit
```

Now you have the wCount it is just a matter of dividing the screen width by that value to get the box render width and multiply the box render width by the box aspect to get the box render height.

```
var rW = w / wCount; // the size of the box to render
var rH = rW * bA; // the height is the width time aspect
```

Sometimes you will get a perfect solution but most times you will not. The actual count will be above of below the requested count due to the rounding. But the fit will be the best for both the required box and screen aspects.

**Demo**

Updates every 3 seconds with a random box size, random screen size (overlaid with green box to show top and bottom excess) Text shows the column and row counts, the requested count and the actual count.

```js
var canvas,ctx;
function createCanvas(){
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.left     = "0px";
    canvas.style.top      = "0px";
    canvas.style.zIndex   = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}

function resize(){
    if(canvas === undefined){
        createCanvas();
    }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
}
window.addEventListener("resize",resize);
resize();


var w = 10;
var h = 20;
var c = 100;
var sW = canvas.width*0.7;
var sH = canvas.height*0.5;
var sA = sH /sW;
var bA = h / w;
function getParticleWidth(particleImageX,particleImageY,w,h,particleCount){
    var a = particleImageY / particleImageX; // get particle aspect
    var c = particleCount; // same with this
    var b = h/w    
    
    return Math.sqrt((c/b)*a)
}

function drawTheParticles(){
    var x,y;
    pCount = Math.round(Math.sqrt((c/sA)*bA));
    var pWidth = sW / pCount;
    var pHeight = pWidth * bA;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear last result
    var cc = 0;
    var sx = (canvas.width-sW)/2;
    var sy = (canvas.height-sH)/2;
    var hc = ((Math.ceil(sH / pHeight)*pHeight)-sH)/2;
    var wc =0;
    for(y = 0; y < sH; y += pHeight){
        for(x = 0; x < sW-(pWidth/2); x += pWidth){
            ctx.fillRect(x + 1+sx-wc, y + 1+sy-hc, pWidth - 2, pHeight - 2);
            ctx.strokeRect(x + 1+sx-wc, y + 1+sy-hc, pWidth - 2, pHeight - 2);
            cc ++;
        }
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(50,200,70,0.25)";
    ctx.fillRect(sx, sy, sW, sH);
    ctx.strokeRect(sx, sy, sW, sH);
    
    // show the details
    ctx.font = "20px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    var str = ""+pCount+" by "+Math.ceil(sH / pHeight)+" need " + c + " got "+cc;
    var width = ctx.measureText(str).width;
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    // clear an area for text
    // with a shadow and not the stupid built in shadow
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    ctx.fillRect((canvas.width / 2) - (width + 8) / 2+6, (canvas.height / 2) - 14+6, width + 8, 28  );
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
    ctx.fillRect((canvas.width / 2) - (width + 8) / 2, (canvas.height / 2) - 14, width + 8, 28  );
    ctx.fillRect((canvas.width / 2) - (width + 8) / 2, (canvas.height / 2) - 14, width + 8, 28  );
    // now draw the text with a bit of an outline
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeText(str, canvas.width/2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillText(str, canvas.width/2, canvas.height / 2);
    
    // And set up to do it all again in 3 seconds
    // get random particle image size
    w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 10);
    h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 10);
    // get random particle count
    c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 10);
    // get random screen width height
    sW = canvas.height*(Math.random()*0.4 + 0.6);
    sH = canvas.height*(Math.random()*0.6 + 0.4);
    // recaculate aspects
    sA = sH /sW;
    bA = h / w;    
    
    // redo it in 3 seconds

    setTimeout(drawTheParticles,3000)
}


drawTheParticles()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found some helpful things in your post and have a pretty good prototype running now.